# AWS CodePipeline Build/Deploy Individual Projects

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-serverless

I would like to develop a Visual Studio 2017 solution with multiple serverless lambda application projects in it. I have successfully developed and deployed a single serverless project with GitHub, CodePipeline, CodeBuild, and CloudFormation, but I can't find any documentation indicating if it's possible to implement multiple stacks with individual build/deploy pipelines.

The projects logically fit into a single GitHub repo/Visual Studio solution, but I don't want to have to build/deploy all of them every time I push to the repo. If it was possible to specify a branch *and* a project in the CodePipeline "source" stage, that would do the trick, but I just don't see it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not very clear... Do u have more than one project under the same repo? Why?

Comment: @Cleriston I'm not sure if you're familiar with Visual Studio, but it's quite common to have multiple projects in a single solution, and have that solution map to a GitHub repository. The projects I have are logically related, and it would make sense for them to be in a single solution/repository. I just don't want a change for one project to kick off a CP run for all projects, but I don't see a way to map a CP build to a project within a repo: only a way to map at the repo level.

Comment: "and a project in the CodePipeline "source" stage" I'm not familiar with Visual Studio, but is there a different argument you can pass in the CodeBuild buildspec to specify which project to build? Then you can have separate pipelines with separate CodeBuild projects.

Comment: @TimB Yes, I'm almost positive that you can specify a buildspec per project, but that still doesn't solve the fact that the CodePipeline execution is fired by a repo push. You could build each project as a separate CloudFormation stack, but you'd still be building all of them for every push, not just the project that had changes.

Comment: Right, but can you configure your build to only build one project even though the repository contains code for multiple projects? You'd obviously still pull excess code from GitHub but the overhead of that is probably low and you'd cut down significantly on your build time.

Comment: @TimB I see what you're saying: if you had only one buildspec for the repo, and it pointed to a specific project, that is the only one that would build. Problem is you'd need to manually edit it for each push depending on which project you wanted to build, which kind of ruins the automated part of the build. Technically it would work, it's just not what I'm looking for. Thanks for the thought, though.

Comment: @LandonC I am sorry, I have moved from Microsoft and I forgot the concept of solution. Back to the problem, the projects of your solution are correlated, therefore it does make sense all the tests be triggered and all the code be pushed. This way you will keep the code consistent and will assess the integration of your solution.